# Testing that class instance supplied to mock function has correct attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have a class `MyClass` and two functions `my_function` and `my_other_function`. `my_other_function` calls `my_function`. I would like to test `my_other_function` and mock out `my_function`. The problem is, `my_function` takes an instance of `MyClass` as its argument and accesses the `foo` attribute of it. `my_other_function` alters the `foo` attribute. I want to test that the calls made to the mock `my_function` use the correct arguments, which involves ensuring that that the `foo` attribute of the `MyClass` instance is correct each time. I'm not sure how to do this because by the time I access the `call_args_list` attribute of the mock the class has already been modified and I can only see its most recent state

```
import mock
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'a'

def my_function(instance):
    print instance.foo


def my_other_function():
    myinstance = MyClass()
    for i in ['a','b','c']:
        myinstance.foo = i 
        my_function(myinstance)


def test_my_other_function():
    with mock.patch(__name__+'.my_function') as mock_function:
        my_other_function()
        mock_function.call_args_list
        # Test that the instance passed to my_function had the correct foo attribute each time
```

Each call in the `calls_args_list` just shows the most recent state of `myinstance`, with `foo` being 'c'